# Scope function name is displayed instead of value when page loaded

Tags: angularjs

In the following AngularJS code, there is a TextArea and a span to display remaining characters allowed. [Total characters allowed is 100]

When I type value in textarea, it displays remaining character count correctly. But when the page is loaded first time, it doesn't show it correctly - it just shows as `{{remaining()}}`.

What change is needed to make it display remaining count as 100, when the page loaded first time? Also, what is the mistake in this code - is it in the use of scope?

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
   var TextLimitController= function ($scope) 
   {
    $scope.remaining = function (countryPopulation) {
        return 100 - $scope.message.length;
    };
   };
</script>

</head>

<body ng-app>

     <div ng-controller="TextLimitController">
    <span> Remaining: {{remaining()}}   </span>
    <div>   
        <textarea ng-model = "message">  {{message}} </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>   

</body>

</html>
```

First time Load

[image]

After Typing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.message` is not initialised to a value so when your view attempts to bind to `$scope.remaining()` it will likely throw an error because `message` is not defined and it can't deref the `.length` property.

Initialise `$scope.message` to an empty string to get the behaviour you desire:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var TextLimitController= function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = '';
        $scope.remaining = function (countryPopulation) {
            return 100 - $scope.message.length;
        };
   };
</script>
```

Also, you should consider using a more recent version of angular; 1.0.7 is *very* out of date and there have been a lot of bug fixes since it was released.

Answer (score 0):

Use local angular js file instead of using link of cdn

And intilaize $scope.message =''

Answer (score -1):

your code should be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n1hxv1jc/), please have a try:

```
    <html ng-app="App">
        <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">  
        angular.module('App',[])  
        .controller('TextLimitController',function($scope){
        $scope.message= "";
        $scope.maxLength = 100;
            $scope.remainingFunc = function () {
               $scope.remaining = $scope.maxLength - $scope.message.length;
            };
        $scope.remainingFunc();        
})

        </script>

        </head>

        <body>

             <div ng-controller="TextLimitController">
            <span> Remaining: {{remaining}}</span>
            <div>   
                <textarea ng-init="" message="" ng-model="message" ng-change="remainingFunc()"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>   

        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the underlying problem

Comment: @DeanWard do you have a try? if you have a try, please tell me what error you meet!

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/xdc77wse/1 - doesn't fix the remaining characters not displaying on initial load.